# Automatically add date for each day in SQL

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery

I'm working on BigQuery and have created a view using multiple tables. Each day data needs to be synced with multiple platforms. I need to insert a date or some other field via SQL through which I can identify which rows were added into the view each day or which rows got updated so only that data I can take forward each day instead of syncing all every day. Best way I can think is to somehow add the the current date wherever an update to a row happens but that date needs to be constant until a further update happens for that record.

Ex:
[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QWDO.png)

Say we get the view T1 on 1st September and T2 on 2nd. I need to to only spot ID:2 for 1st September and ID:3,4,5 on 2nd September. Note: no such date column is there.I need help in creating such column or any other approach to verify which rows are getting updated/added daily

Comment: Could you provide some example data and expected output ?

Comment: Hi Sujit,
I've added an example. Please verify and see if it clarifies

Comment: This is usually handled via the partitioning key on the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `BigQuery schedule queries` with frequency as daily (24 hours) using below INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO dataset.T1
SELECT
  *
FROM
  dataset.T2
WHERE
  date > (SELECT MAX(date) FROM dataset.T1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table where the data is getting streamed to (in your case: sample data) needs to be configured as a partitioned table. Therefor you use "Partition by ingestion time" so that you don't need to handle the date yourself.
[Configuration in BQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcojV.png)

After you recreated that table append your existing data to that new table with the help of the format options in BQ (append) and RUN.

Then you create a view based on that table with:

```
SELECT * EXCEPT (rank)
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (GROUP BY invoice_id ORDER BY _PARTITIONTIME desc) AS rank
  FROM `your_dataset.your_sample_data_table`
)
WHERE rank = 1
```

Always use the view from that on.